# vertical scroll bar in IE6

Tags: .net, css, html

I am facing problem on div tag with vertical scroll. When I minimize the window the scroll bar does not appear in a small size window. I am using Window Server 2003 sp2 and IE6 as client.

Below is my div tag..

```
<div style="border: 1 none Black; vertical-align: top;overflow:auto; height:470px; width:980px;"
class="content">
```

CSS:

```
.content
{
font-size: 11px;
background: url(../Images/bg-content.jpg) repeat-x top center;
padding: 20px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: **Why do you have IE6?!**

Comment: our customer use IE6, so i have no choice on this.

Comment: ...who is your customer? If anyone has IE6 they **really** need an upgrade.... It's been 10 years since IE6

Comment: You might find that it's better to stop doing business with that customer as it's clearly hindering progress for other things...

Comment: [Aye, pirates be the reason IE6 just won’t die](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/08/aye-pirates-be-reason-ie6-just-wont-die.html)

Comment: How do you mean `border: 1 none Black` ? Do you need border or not? `border: 1px solid Black;` maybe? If it is none it can't be black. If you want border to be invisible make it the same colour as background.

Comment: @SwetaPriya Why not explain him about new technologies  or just upgrade the browser for him. If he still have IE6 , I am sure he doesnt care about or know much about latest stuff .. so present him the new IE10 and save up some work .

Comment: If you MUST support legacy browsers, I would suggest making things easier on yourself. https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ .... Use IE9.js. It'll make IE5.5 and up act like IE9 as far as HTML and CSS goes.

Comment: @SwetaPriya Please let me know if it got resolved .

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the property overflow:auto; Ie6 had issues with it . You can add the following two properties in your css something like :

```
_overflow:hidden;
_overflow-y: visible;
```